# An organisation related to science fiction monsters

Tags: story-identification, horror

There is an organisation that monitors some of the most dangerous creatures.

I don't know the name of the organisation, but maybe they are called "SCF" or "SFM" or "SF" or something similar.  The creatures' names are numbered like "SF 100" or "SF 144".

Does anyone know of this organisation, and can they tell me the name of it?

Comment: Are you looking for a specific story/work with this basic premise? It’s a bit unclear what you’re asking here. You can [edit] your question to clear that up.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clearer (I believe), feel free to roll back the edit if this changes your question.  Also please take the [tour](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and welcome to SF&F

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 34):

I believe you are looking for the [SCP Foundation](http://www.scp-wiki.net/about-the-scp-foundation) stories.

> Operating clandestine and worldwide, the Foundation operates beyond jurisdiction, empowered and entrusted by every major national government with the task of containing anomalous objects, entities, and phenomena. These anomalies pose a significant threat to global security by threatening either physical or psychological harm.
>
> The Foundation operates to maintain normalcy, so that the worldwide civilian population can live and go on with their daily lives without fear, mistrust, or doubt in their personal beliefs, and to maintain human independence from extraterrestrial, extradimensional, and other extranormal influence.
>
> Our mission is three-fold:
>
> ### Secure
>
> The Foundation secures anomalies with the goal of preventing them from falling into the hands of civilian or rival agencies, through extensive observation and surveillance and by acting to intercept such anomalies at the earliest opportunity.
>
> ### Contain
>
> The Foundation contains anomalies with the goal of preventing their influence or effects from spreading, by either relocating, concealing, or dismantling such anomalies or by suppressing or preventing public dissemination of knowledge thereof.
>
> ### Protect
>
> The Foundation protects humanity from the effects of such anomalies as well as the anomalies themselves until such time that they are either fully understood or new theories of science can be devised based on their properties and behavior. The Foundation may also neutralize or destroy anomalies as an option of last resort, if they are determined to be too dangerous to be contained.